# istio upgrade from 1.4.6 -> 1.5.0 throws istiod erros : remote error: tls: error decrypting message

Tags: istio, amazon-eks, envoyproxy

Just upgraded istio from 1.4.6 (helm) to istio 1.5.0 (istioctl) [Purged istio and installed from istioctl] but it appears the istiod logs keep throwing the following :

```
2020-03-16T18:25:45.209055Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.56.111:56870": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:46.792447Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.57.112:49162": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:46.930483Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.56.160:36878": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:48.284122Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.52.230:44758": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:48.288180Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.57.149:56756": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:49.108515Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.57.151:53970": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:49.111874Z info    Handling event update for pod contentgatewayaidest-7f4694d87-qmq8z in namespace djin-content -> 10.150.53.50
2020-03-16T18:25:49.519861Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.57.91:59510": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:50.133664Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.57.203:59726": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:50.331020Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.57.195:59970": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
2020-03-16T18:25:52.110695Z info    Handling event update for pod contentgateway-d74b44c7-dtdxs in namespace djin-content -> 10.150.56.215
2020-03-16T18:25:53.312761Z info    Handling event update for pod dysonpriority-b6dbc589b-mk628 in namespace djin-content -> 10.150.52.91
2020-03-16T18:25:53.496524Z info    grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.150.56.111:57276": remote error: tls: error decrypting message
```

This also leads to no sidecars successfully launching and failing with :

```
2020-03-16T18:32:17.265394Z info    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 16 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 0 rejected
2020-03-16T18:32:19.269334Z info    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 16 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 0 rejected
2020-03-16T18:32:21.265214Z info    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 16 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 0 rejected
2020-03-16T18:32:23.266159Z info    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 16 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful,
```

Weirdly other clusters that I upgraded go through fine. Any idea where this error might be popping up from ? istioctl analyze works fine.

error goes away after killing the nodes (recreating) but istio-proxies still fail with :

**info Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 1 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 0 rejected**

Comment: Could you try use [istioctl upgrade](https://istio.io/docs/setup/upgrade/istioctl-upgrade/) instead of purge and install? As far as I remember i had same problem and upgrade fixed it.

Comment: I had a similar issue even when I was using a fresh installation with the same step as 1.4.6. Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know since version 1.4.4 they add istioctl upgrade, which should be used when You want to upgrade istio from 1.4.x to 1.5.0.

---

> The istioctl upgrade command performs an upgrade of Istio. Before performing the upgrade, it checks that the Istio installation meets the upgrade eligibility criteria. Also, it alerts the user if it detects any changes in the profile default values between Istio versions.
>
> The upgrade command can also perform a downgrade of Istio.
>
> See the [istioctl upgrade](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/#istioctl-upgrade) reference for all the options provided by the istioctl upgrade command.

---

```
istioctl upgrade --help
```

> The upgrade command checks for upgrade version eligibility and, if eligible, upgrades the Istio control plane components in-place. Warning: traffic may be disrupted during upgrade. Please ensure PodDisruptionBudgets are defined to maintain service continuity.

---

I made a test on gcp cluster with istio 1.4.6 installed with istioctl and then I used istioctl upgrade from version 1.5.0 and everything works fine.

```
kubectl get pods -n istio-system
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-ingressgateway-598796f4d9-lvzdb   1/1     Running   0          12m
istiod-7d9c7bdd6-mggx7                  1/1     Running   0          12m
prometheus-b47d8c58c-7spq5              2/2     Running   0          12m
```

I checked the logs and made some simple examples and no errors occurs in istiod like in your example.

---

**Upgrade prerequisites for istioctl upgrade**

---

```
Ensure you meet these requirements before starting the upgrade process:

Istio version 1.4.4 or higher is installed.

Your Istio installation was installed using istioctl.
```

---

I assume because of the differences between 1.4.x and 1.5.0 there might be some issues when you want to use both of the installatio methods, helm and istioctl. The best option here would be to install istio 1.4.6 with istioctl and then upgrade it to 1.5.0.

---

I hope this answer your question. Let me know if you have any more questions.